# Count Specific Words in a string

Tags: sql, count, words

Need your assistance please. I need to write a query to count the number of times the word 'user' appears in the below string.

I'am currently using the below select query however the counts are not accurate.

```
(len(CallEventLog) - len(replace(CallEventLog, 'user',' ')))/ len('user') as #ofTransfers_Users
```

09:06:56: Initializing
09:06:56: Offering
09:06:56: ANI:  33327368876
09:06:56: DNIS:  7885
09:06:56: Call answered
09:06:56: Call entered IVR: CF1Residential
09:06:57: IVR: CF1Residential
09:07:41: Offering
09:07:41: Entered Workgroup ACDNewMoving
09:07:41: ACD - Wait Agent
09:08:33: ACD interaction assigned to kmara
09:08:33: Offering
09:08:33: Sent to user kmara
09:08:35: Connected
09:08:35: Sent to station GPD6T5432S
09:08:35: ACD interaction connected to kmara
09:08:35: ACD - Assigned: kmara
09:09:40: Held
09:12:33: Connected
09:12:33: Entered Workgroup ACDMetering
09:12:33: Sent to user fwinger
09:14:16: Disconnected [Local Hang Up]
09:14:16: Local Disconnect

Thanks

Comment: The change that James suggested worked for counting 'User' worked, however only up it 3. for eg the logs that had 4 instances of 'User', the query counted this as 7.

Comment: Do you have some more example strings?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your query is that you are replacing the value 'user' with a space character, but it should be an empty string. So instead of:

```
(len(CallEventLog) - len(replace(CallEventLog, 'user',' ')))/ len('user') as #ofTransfers_Users
```

do this:

```
(len(CallEventLog) - len(replace(CallEventLog, 'user','')))/ len('user') as #ofTransfers_Users
```

Comment: Hey James , Read the additional comments on how my query is not counting quite correctly.